# How can i use webpack in .net 6?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, webpack, razor-pages

How can I use webpack in .net6 razor pages? Any documentation I've found on the internet about this just confuses me more.

this is my file1.ts:

```
export function CCC(): string {
    return "AAAAAA";
}
```

this is my file.ts:

```
import { CCC } from "./file1"

function AAA(): string {
    return CCC();
}
```

this is my Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<script>
const str = AAA()
alert(str);
</script>
```

this is my layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TypeScriptLab5</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/TypeScriptLab5.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <script src="~/ts/file1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ts/file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

this is my program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I hope I have given enough explanation to present my problem

Answer (score 0):

For webpack 5 and net 6 follow these steps:

1. install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/)
2. create an asp.net core 6 application
3. Add the following configuration files

package.json configuration file

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "here is my app description",
  "private": true,//make packages private and prevent an accidental publish of your code
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.78.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './wwwroot/scripts/app.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         test: /\.tsx?$/,
         use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js','.tsx', '.ts'],
  },
  output: {
    library: {
      name: 'app_name',
      type: 'var'
    },
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../scripts'),
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I assume `typescript` for these configs and you can use javascript instead.

Add bundled scripts in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
```

Now you can bundle project modules using `> npm run build` command.